# Jetpack Compose partial or open side border

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to draw partial or one-side open rect rounded border to achieve this effect:

[image]

After playing around a bit I got this:

[image]

This is done via:

```kotlin
RoundedCornerShape(topStartPercent = 50, bottomStartPercent = 50) // start
RoundedCornerShape(topEndPercent = 50, bottomEndPercent = 50) // end
RectangleShape // for middle
```

What I want is to remove the connecting vertical lines between the cells.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can draw border behind Composables using Modifier.drawBehind and checking if your Composable is at the start, center or end

```
enum class BorderOrder {
    Start, Center, End
}

fun Modifier.drawSegmentedBorder(
    strokeWidth: Dp,
    color: Color,
    cornerPercent: Int,
    borderOrder: BorderOrder,
    drawDivider: Boolean = false
) = composed(
    factory = {

        val density = LocalDensity.current
        val strokeWidthPx = density.run { strokeWidth.toPx() }

        Modifier.drawBehind {
            val width = size.width
            val height = size.height
            val cornerRadius = height * cornerPercent / 100

            when (borderOrder) {
                BorderOrder.Start -> {

                    drawLine(
                        color = color,
                        start = Offset(x = width, y = 0f),
                        end = Offset(x = cornerRadius, y = 0f),
                        strokeWidth = strokeWidthPx
                    )

                    // Top left arc
                    drawArc(
                        color = color,
                        startAngle = 180f,
                        sweepAngle = 90f,
                        useCenter = false,
                        topLeft = Offset.Zero,
                        size = Size(cornerRadius * 2, cornerRadius * 2),
                        style = Stroke(width = strokeWidthPx)
                    )
                    drawLine(
                        color = color,
                        start = Offset(x = 0f, y = cornerRadius),
                        end = Offset(x = 0f, y = height - cornerRadius),
                        strokeWidth = strokeWidthPx
                    )
                    // Bottom left arc
                    drawArc(
                        color = color,
                        startAngle = 90f,
                        sweepAngle = 90f,
                        useCenter = false,
                        topLeft = Offset(x = 0f, y = height - 2 * cornerRadius),
                        size = Size(cornerRadius * 2, cornerRadius * 2),
                        style = Stroke(width = strokeWidthPx)
                    )
                    drawLine(
                        color = color,
                        start = Offset(x = cornerRadius, y = height),
                        end = Offset(x = width, y = height),
                        strokeWidth = strokeWidthPx
                    )
                }
                BorderOrder.Center -> {
                    drawLine(
                        color = color,
                        start = Offset(x = 0f, y = 0f),
                        end = Offset(x = width, y = 0f),
                        strokeWidth = strokeWidthPx
                    )
                    drawLine(
                        color = color,
                        start = Offset(x = 0f, y = height),
                        end = Offset(x = width, y = height),
                        strokeWidth = strokeWidthPx
                    )

                    if (drawDivider) {
                        drawLine(
                            color = color,
                            start = Offset(x = 0f, y = 0f),
                            end = Offset(x = 0f, y = height),
                            strokeWidth = strokeWidthPx
                        )
                    }
                }
                else -> {

                    if (drawDivider) {
                        drawLine(
                            color = color,
                            start = Offset(x = 0f, y = 0f),
                            end = Offset(x = 0f, y = height),
                            strokeWidth = strokeWidthPx
                        )
                    }

                    drawLine(
                        color = color,
                        start = Offset(x = 0f, y = 0f),
                        end = Offset(x = width - cornerRadius, y = 0f),
                        strokeWidth = strokeWidthPx
                    )

                    // Top right arc
                    drawArc(
                        color = color,
                        startAngle = 270f,
                        sweepAngle = 90f,
                        useCenter = false,
                        topLeft = Offset(x = width - cornerRadius * 2, y = 0f),
                        size = Size(cornerRadius * 2, cornerRadius * 2),
                        style = Stroke(width = strokeWidthPx)
                    )
                    drawLine(
                        color = color,
                        start = Offset(x = width, y = cornerRadius),
                        end = Offset(x = width, y = height - cornerRadius),
                        strokeWidth = strokeWidthPx
                    )
                    // Bottom right arc
                    drawArc(
                        color = color,
                        startAngle = 0f,
                        sweepAngle = 90f,
                        useCenter = false,
                        topLeft = Offset(
                            x = width - 2 * cornerRadius,
                            y = height - 2 * cornerRadius
                        ),
                        size = Size(cornerRadius * 2, cornerRadius * 2),
                        style = Stroke(width = strokeWidthPx)
                    )
                    drawLine(
                        color = color,
                        start = Offset(x = 0f, y = height),
                        end = Offset(x = width -cornerRadius, y = height),
                        strokeWidth = strokeWidthPx
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
)
```

Usage

```
@Composable
private fun SegmentedBorderSample() {
    Row {
        repeat(3) {

            val order = when (it) {
                0 -> BorderOrder.Start
                2 -> BorderOrder.End
                else -> BorderOrder.Center
            }

            Box(
                contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(40.dp)
                    .drawSegmentedBorder(
                        strokeWidth = 2.dp,
                        color = Color.Green,
                        borderOrder = order,
                        cornerPercent = 40,
                        drawDivider = false
                    )
                    .padding(4.dp)
            ) {
                Text(text = "$it")
            }
        }
    }


    Row {
        repeat(4) {

            val order = when (it) {
                0 -> BorderOrder.Start
                3 -> BorderOrder.End
                else -> BorderOrder.Center
            }

            Box(
                contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(40.dp)
                    .drawSegmentedBorder(
                        strokeWidth = 2.dp,
                        color = Color.Cyan,
                        borderOrder = order,
                        cornerPercent = 50,
                        drawDivider = true
                    )
                    .padding(4.dp)
            ) {
                Text(text = "$it")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result

[image]

Comment: You are welcome. This by nature of `Modifier.drawBehind` draws behind of your Composable. If you want borders to be drawn on top of a composable with background for instance use `Modifier.drawWithContent{drawContent() // rest of the drawing`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `offset` modifier to avoid the double border:

Something like:

```
val itemsList = (0..4).toList()

Row() {
    itemsList.forEachIndexed { index, item ->
        OutlinedButton(
            onClick = { /** do something */},
            modifier = when (index) {
                0 ->
                    Modifier
                        .offset(0.dp, 0.dp)
                else ->
                    Modifier
                        .offset((-1 * index).dp, 0.dp)
            },
            shape = when (index) {
                // left outer button
                0 -> RoundedCornerShape(topStart = cornerRadius, topEnd = 0.dp, bottomStart = cornerRadius, bottomEnd = 0.dp)
                // right outer button
                itemsList.size - 1 -> RoundedCornerShape(topStart = 0.dp, topEnd = cornerRadius, bottomStart = 0.dp, bottomEnd = cornerRadius)
                // middle button
                else -> RoundedCornerShape(0.dp)
            },
            border = BorderStroke(1.dp, Blue500)
        ) {}
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: what does `offset` do any article for this ? I don't have experience for this. I want to understand how `offset` works.

Comment: @vivekmodi Modifier.offset changes position of Composable or interactions after that modifier. This answer moves items from original position by 1.dp and it would be more apparent if border stroke is bigger. This is not desired outcome espcially when you have other items that can be used as reference

Comment: Looks simpler and usable for minor tasks, but introduces Color + actual view size problems.