# How to consecutive square item as OTP in jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

How to achieve the consecutive square item as OTP, the first and last item as rounded in jetpack compose.[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74606072/jetpack-compose-partial-or-open-side-border